# ServiceControl Events HeartbeatStopped not working

Tags: c#, microservices, nservicebus

I am trying to trigger an alert when nservicebus host stops running so added custom events following below article, but when I stopped the host in server it's not firing the event.
I see this host as inactive in service pulse but i am not seeing any errors i logged in new relic.
https://docs.particular.net/samples/servicecontrol/events-subscription/
I am using nservicebus 5.2.14 .

here is the code.

```
   public class CustomEventsHandler :
    IHandleMessages<HeartbeatStopped>,
    IHandleMessages<HeartbeatRestored>
{
    public void Handle(HeartbeatStopped message)
    {
        NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.NoticeError($"Heartbeats from {message.EndpointName} have stopped.", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Context", "ServiceHostStatus" } });

    }

    public void Handle(HeartbeatRestored message)
    {
        NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.NoticeError($"Heartbeats from {message.EndpointName} have been restored.", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Context", "ServiceHostStatus" } });

    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you see heartbeat stopped notification in ServicePulse?

Comment: yes , i see the end point in inactive state in service pulse.

Comment: no, inactive is ServiceControl's way of saying this endpoint is not processing messages.
 I'm asking do you get the heartbeat failing event in SP https://docs.particular.net/servicepulse/images/dashboard-overview.png

You can start with an empty database as a test start the endpoints and see if you get the heartbeat received event in ServicePulse If you do than it means ServiceControl is publishing the events ok and the plugin is installed and configured correctly.

Comment: Maybe reach out to support@particular.net?